# SQL or Pyspark - Get the last time a column had a different value for each ID

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark so I have tried both pyspark code and SQL.

I am trying to get the time that the ADDRESS column was a different value, grouped by USER_ID. The rows are ordered by TIME. Take the below table:

```
    +---+-------+-------+----+
    | ID|USER_ID|ADDRESS|TIME|
    +---+-------+-------+----+
    |  1|      1|      A|  10|
    |  2|      1|      B|  15|
    |  3|      1|      A|  20|
    |  4|      1|      A|  40|
    |  5|      1|      A|  45|
    +---+-------+-------+----+
```

The correct new column I would like is as below:

```
    +---+-------+-------+----+---------+
    | ID|USER_ID|ADDRESS|TIME|LAST_DIFF|
    +---+-------+-------+----+---------+
    |  1|      1|      A|  10|     null|
    |  2|      1|      B|  15|       10|
    |  3|      1|      A|  20|       15|
    |  4|      1|      A|  40|       15|
    |  5|      1|      A|  45|       15|
    +---+-------+-------+----+---------+
```

I have tried using different windows but none ever seem to get exactly what I want. Any ideas?

Comment: which column? how do you specify the row order?

Comment: edited the question, looking at last time ADDRESS column was different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplified version of @jxc's answer.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Window
#Window definition
w = Window.partitionBy(col('user_id')).orderBy(col('id'))
#Getting the previous time and classifying rows into groups
grp_df = df.withColumn('grp',sum(when(lag(col('address')).over(w) == col('address'),0).otherwise(1)).over(w)) \
           .withColumn('prev_time',lag(col('time')).over(w))
#Window definition with groups
w_grp = Window.partitionBy(col('user_id'),col('grp')).orderBy(col('id'))
grp_df.withColumn('last_addr_change_time',min(col('prev_time')).over(w_grp)).show()
```

- Use `lag` with running `sum` to assign groups when there is a change in the column value (based on the defined window). Get the time from the previous row, which will be used in the next step.
- Once you get the groups, use the running `min`imum to get the last timestamp of the column value change. (Suggest you look at the intermediate results to understand the transformations better)

Answer (score 1):

One way using two Window specs:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col, lag, sum as fsum
from pyspark.sql import Window

w1 = Window.partitionBy('USER_ID').orderBy('ID')
w2 = Window.partitionBy('USER_ID').orderBy('g')

# create a new sub-group label based on the values of ADDRESS and Previous ADDRESS
df1 = df.withColumn('g', fsum(when(col('ADDRESS') == lag('ADDRESS').over(w1), 0).otherwise(1)).over(w1))

# group by USER_ID and the above sub-group label and calculate the sum of time in the group as diff
# calculate the last_diff and then join the data back to the df1
df2 = df1.groupby('USER_ID', 'g').agg(fsum('Time').alias('diff')).withColumn('last_diff', lag('diff').over(w2))

df1.join(df2, on=['USER_ID', 'g']).show()
+-------+---+---+-------+----+----+---------+                               
|USER_ID|  g| ID|ADDRESS|TIME|diff|last_diff|
+-------+---+---+-------+----+----+---------+
|      1|  1|  1|      A|  10|  10|     null|
|      1|  2|  2|      B|  15|  15|       10|
|      1|  3|  3|      A|  20| 105|       15|
|      1|  3|  4|      A|  40| 105|       15|
|      1|  3|  5|      A|  45| 105|       15|
+-------+---+---+-------+----+----+---------+

df_new = df1.join(df2, on=['USER_ID', 'g']).drop('g', 'diff')
```