# identify the most recent record different from the current value in a PySpark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rolling-computation

I have a PySpark dataframe, where each user has a certain status at a point in time, as in the dummy data below

```
    --------------------------
    |user_id| status| month  |
    --------------------------
    | 1     | A     | 12/2020|
    | 1     | A     | 11/2020|
    | 1     | B     | 10/2020|
    | 1     | B     | 09/2020|
    | 1     | A     | 08/2020|
    | 1     | C     | 07/2020|
    | 2     | A     | 12/2020|
    | 2     | A     | 11/2020|
    | 2     | A     | 10/2020|
    | 2     | B     | 09/2020|
```

I would like to create in my PySpark dataframe another two columns (previous_status_value and previous_status_month), which for each record indicate what was the most recent date when the user had a different status than the one in the record, and what was that value. With the above dummy data, the result would be

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |user_id| status| month  | previous_status_value| previous_status_month|
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | 1     | A     | 12/2020| B                    | 10/2020              |
    | 1     | A     | 11/2020| B                    | 10/2020              |
    | 1     | B     | 10/2020| A                    | 08/2020              |
    | 1     | B     | 09/2020| A                    | 08/2020              |
    | 1     | A     | 08/2020| C                    | 07/2020              |
    | 1     | C     | 07/2020| Null                 | Null                 |
    | 2     | A     | 12/2020| B                    | 09/2020              |
    | 2     | A     | 11/2020| B                    | 09/2020              |
    | 2     | A     | 10/2020| B                    | 09/2020              |
    | 2     | B     | 09/2020| Null                 | Null                 |
```

The dataframe has millions of records, so I was trying to approach this using Window functions (similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59198003/sql-or-pyspark-get-the-last-time-a-column-had-a-different-value-for-each-id)) but didn't get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find where the status changes using `lead`, only keep the `status` and `month` that corresponds to status changes and mask with null otherwise using `when(F.col('begin'), F.col('status'))`, and get the previous value using `F.last(..., ignorenulls=True)`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('user_id').orderBy('month')
begin = F.lead('status').over(w) != F.col('status')
df = df.select('*', begin.alias('begin'))

w = w.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)
previous_status_value = F.last(F.when(F.col('begin'), F.col('status')), ignorenulls=True).over(w).alias('previous_status_value')
previous_status_month = F.last(F.when(F.col('begin'), F.col('month')), ignorenulls=True).over(w).alias('previous_status_month ')

df = df.select('*', previous_status_value, previous_status_month).drop('begin').orderBy('user_id', F.col('month').desc())

df.show()
+-------+------+-------+---------------------+----------------------+
|user_id|status|  month|previous_status_value|previous_status_month |
+-------+------+-------+---------------------+----------------------+
|      1|     A|12/2020|                    B|               10/2020|
|      1|     A|11/2020|                    B|               10/2020|
|      1|     B|10/2020|                    A|               08/2020|
|      1|     B|09/2020|                    A|               08/2020|
|      1|     A|08/2020|                    C|               07/2020|
|      1|     C|07/2020|                 null|                  null|
|      2|     A|12/2020|                    B|               09/2020|
|      2|     A|11/2020|                    B|               09/2020|
|      2|     A|10/2020|                    B|               09/2020|
|      2|     B|09/2020|                 null|                  null|
+-------+------+-------+---------------------+----------------------+
```